# django-rest and angular nginx load static image issue

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-staticfiles, static-files

hi im trying to load my angular app with nginx everything work except static image that are part of template (product image that are saved in upload folder are ok) 
 this is the related code of setting.py :

```
MEDIA_URL = '/upload/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upload')


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname((__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

and this is my index file in /static/ folder:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" id="persain">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>M4new</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.4bdc8f4141f772a8814a.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<app-root>Loading . . .</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polyfills.b0205464c9bd4e7fe3b3.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts.59ed76cc23ba77b0ec72.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.159b545905e86c2df1d4.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my static directory is like this :

[image: static folder]

and my result :

[image: result with 404 for image]

as you see image cant load because they lose static keyword in begin of url .

i tried `Python manage.py collectstatic` and i add

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to end of my url but nothing changed .... any idea for this issue? thanks

---

more info :
nginx config:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;


      location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/mohammadreza/PycharmProjects/ac2/academy/academy;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Access-Control-Allow-Orgin,XMLHttpRequest,Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/mohammadreza/PycharmProjects/ac2/academy.sock;
    }
```

note : i have same problem in gunicorn too.

Comment: add your Nginx config too, and url of failed images ( with firebug or something like that)

Comment: i added nginx config . you can see failed  images url in socond image in my post check where i wrote"my result" 
 .. i think this issue is independent to nginx because i have this broblem with gunicorn  too

Answer (score 0):

You should change your URLs to `static` return correct URL

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + \
               static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and change `STATIC_ROOT` to `static`

currently, your project generates URL wrongly, they should be replaced with /static.file to /static/static.file

with the above solution, I think you can handle the problem